Somehow counter in c# unity script adds 2 instead of 1
I have this piece of code which detects when the wall passes the player, and increases the counter. For some reason, the chunk sometimes stays in the same position twice, adding to the counter twice. I think there is nothing wrong, and the problem is in Unity itself.
for (int i = 0; i < SpawnedChunks.Count; i++)
{   
    float playerX = Player.transform.position.x;
    float chunkX = SpawnedChunks[i].bot_wall.position.x;

    if (chunkX < playerX && chunkX > -4.5f && GameObject.Find("player"))
    {
        PassedChunks.Add(SpawnedChunks[i]);
        PointsCounter.PointsCount++ ;
    }
}



How are you moving the chunks, with Rigidbodies, or by setting the transform in an Update function? Where is this counter-increasing code being run?

I use rigidbody to move the chunks. Sorry i dont know how to post the full script

Is this for loop that increments the counter in Update()? If so, it needs to be in FixedUpdate() because it relies on the physics system.

Thanks a lot, after I moved everything to fixed update, it worked correctly

Since you're using a Rigidbody to move the walls, you have to place this loop inside of FixedUpdate, instead of Update.
Anything that relies on the physics system (or the results of the physics system) needs to run inside of FixedUpdate. The physics system runs at a set interval (ex. 60 times a second), while Update runs once a frame, which can be higher or lower than 60 times a second. This is why the position only didn't update occasionally, it depends on the ever-changing framerate of your game.
